# how to read contents of a file coming as a single argument to shell script

Tags: shell, cat

I want to pass reference file as an argument to shell script

ref.file contains

```
no=1
desc="query 0 "
src_txt="select count(1) from source"
trg_txt="select count(1) from target"
flag=c

no=2
desc="query 1 "
src_txt="select count(1) from source1"
trg_txt="select count(1) from target1"
flag=c

no=3
desc="query 2 "
src_txt="select count(1) from source2"
trg_txt="select count(1) from target2"
flag=c
```

and so on...

shell comamnd - `sh generic.sh $(cat ref.txt )`

inside shell script I am trying to read the contains of ref.txt

echo "ref-- " $1

It prints only first line i.e. no=1
if i use $2 and so on then it will print only few words not the whole text

How to read the entire file in a variable including new lines and iterate over other queries in ref file in a single go

Comment: that is really a weird way of reading a file. However, you should quote the file to preserve its content. like `sh generic.sh "$(cat ref.file )"` Why not you read the file name and later inside `generic.sh` you read the file `ref.file` as you would want ?

Comment: I modified to make suggested change. but curious to know does it make difference in execution if we read inside file?

Comment: It depends on implementation , it will give you more control to put validations on the input file. You can use while loop to read the file or just cat. There any various ways.

Comment: Given the content of that file, I think, you want to use a shell feature called `source`(ing) a file. This will execute all lines in the supplied filename as if the lines were included in the body of your script. Other languages refer to this feature as "include files". You get that in the shell with either `source myFile` or a shortcut is `. myFile`. . ELSE you can loop thru the file with `while read line ; do echo " processing variable line=$line" ; other cmds as needed ; done < myFile`. .....

Comment: Now inside the `while` loop,  you can process the value of `$line` anyway you need and use all of the language features or other utilities you might need. In general though, you're looking to modify the file you are reading, you'll want to use `awk/sed/perl/python` to change the file rather than rely on processing one line of data with multiple calls to external tools. Good luck

Comment: thanks for response. how to fetch value of variables without using regex, for eg. i want to extract 1 from (no=1) and query 0 from (desc="query 0 ") and so on by just giving variable text

Comment: `source myFile .... ; (other code) ; ... echo $no` should return `1`, and `echo $desc` should return `query 0`. Recommend you search for shell programming tutorials. Good luck.